# Import Oracle Dump file and NOVALIDATE for FKs

Tags: oracle

**Situation**:

I'm exporting data from the Oracle DB A, and importing it into an empty Oracle DB B.
When exporting from A, I deliberately export partially the data in different tables. That results into a dump file that for sure does not guarantee FK integrity due to the ignored data. Then I want to import it into the DB B it fails when creating the FKs.

**Goal**:

I want to have the same effect as NOVALIDATE has for FK Constraints but at import time. That is: for old data, it should not validate, and just check for new data. I didn't find a way to do it on the export, or import. Does any one know how can I do it?

**Extra information**:

- I can't change the FK on the DB A before dumping it.
- The data is so intertwined with old and new data, that there is no way to create the DB B while maintaining the consistency of FKs.
- I need to create the FKs, because the new data will rely on them

Comment: Do you need to import the FKs if they're going to fail? You could just skip them. Or you could only import the metadata, then set the FKs to novalidate then import the data?

Comment: Are you creating the tables and FKs as part of the import, or are you loading data into existing tables with enabled FKs?

Comment: - Ben, good question, yes I need to keep the FKs.

Comment: @Chris, the tables are being create as part of the import, so it's loads into an empty DB.